# importing astyanax library in play framework

Tags: java, playframework, cassandra, astyanax

I have a problem in including external jar files to play framework. I'm trying to include Astyanax to play framework. There are multiple jar files in astyanax after running `./gradlew build`

I made a `/lib` folder in the project folder.

Which jar files should I put in the github repo after using `./gradlew build` ?

Note : I also downloaded `astyanax.jar` file from maven central. I copyied the .jar file but it still shows errors.

Note : I also tried `play eclipse` command. Nothing changed.

Note : I can't use eclipse to add external .jar files. I need to do it on virtual linux server.

Thanks

Comment: try "./gradlew eclipse" or "./play eclipsify"

Comment: there is no `./play eclipsify` but there exists `./play eclipse`. I've tried it. nothing changes. let me try `./gradlew eclipse`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To include an external library, you can just [add a line to your `project/Build.scala`](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.1.1/SBTDependencies).

In your case, that would look like this:

```
val appDependencies = Seq(
  libraryDependencies += "com.netflix.astyanax" % "astyanax" % "0.8.9"
)
```